# How does the change in measurement units affect the slope in linear regression?

Tags: regression

How will a change in units of measurement of the independent variable from Celsius to Fahrenheit change the slope in a simple regression model?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you switch the independent variable to Fahrenheit, your slope will be the slope in Celsius divided by 1.6 (because 1 degree Celsius = 1.6 degrees Fahrenheit). If temperature was your dependent variable instead, you would have to multiply by 1.6.

The intercept will change too, of course.

Comment: Upvoted for the excellence and clarity of the answer.